Laravel Filament afterStateUpdated. Fields not saving to database
I need help understanding why computed fields from an afterStateUpdated hook are not getting sent to the database.
I'm working on a website that has song lyrics. The backend admin is using Filament 3.x and is working fine. I'm working on adding the functionality for attaching online media (e.g. YouTube videos) that can be embedded on the song lyrics page. The functionality I want in the admin is to simply put in the youtube URL and using a MediaService with 3rd party libraries, parse out the URL, grab the video title and other metadata from YouTube, etc. in the filament afterStateUpdated hook.
That all seems to be working.

However, when I try to create and save to the database, I get an error that indicates that only the updated_at and created_at are being sent to the database with the error:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: media.host (Connection: sqlite, SQL: insert into "media" ("updated_at", "created_at") values (2024-06-18 15:55:09, 2024-06-18 15:55:09))

Here is the Media model:
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Media extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['host', 'media_id', 'url', 'title'];
}

Here is the migration for the media table:
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('song_id')
                ->nullable()
                ->constrained()->
                onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('host');
            $table->string('media_id');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

And the form from the Filament MediaResource
    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('input_url')
                    ->label('Media URL')
                    ->live(onBlur: true)
                    ->afterStateUpdated(function (Forms\Set $set, $state) {
                        $mediaService = new MediaService();
                        $parsed = $mediaService->parseUrl($state);
                        if ($parsed) {
                            $set('title', $parsed['title']);
                            $set('host', $parsed['host']);
                            $set('media_id', $parsed['media_id']);
                            $set('url', $parsed['url']);
                        }
                    }),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('title')
                    ->required()
                    ->disabled(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('host')
                    ->required()
                    ->disabled(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('media_id')
                    ->required()
                    ->disabled(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('url')
                    ->required()
                    ->disabled(),
            ]);
    }


I figured out the issue myself by reading the documentation more thoroughly. Using the disabled() property actually prevents the data from being sent to the server. However there is a readOnly() property that allows the data to be sent to the server even though you can't edit it in the form.
For posterity, here is the final code of the form:
    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('input_url')
                    ->label('Media URL')
                    ->live(onBlur: true)
                    ->afterStateUpdated(function (Forms\Set $set, $state, Forms\Components\TextInput $component) {
                        $mediaService = new MediaService();
                        $parsed = $mediaService->parseUrl($state);
                        if ($parsed) {
                            $set('title', $parsed['title']);
                            $set('host', $parsed['host']);
                            $set('media_id', $parsed['media_id']);
                            $set('url', $parsed['url']);
                        }
                    }),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('title')
                    ->required()
                    ->readOnly(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('host')
                    ->required()
                    ->readOnly(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('media_id')
                    ->required()
                    ->readOnly(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('url')
                    ->required()
                    ->readOnly(),
            ]);
    }


